# Suggestion for custom close reason : "reference questions that can be answered by a resource such as a dictionary..."

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/need-the-word-happiness-translated-and-drawn currently looks like a question that could be answered with a dictionary. (I think my own question [What do Koreans call Genghis Khan?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1711/what-do-koreans-call-genghis-khan) could be closed for the same reason, as endic.naver.com gives the answer.)

We are allowed three custom close reasons, and I was wondering if these kind of cases would warrant one. Something like:

> Simple reference questions that can be answered by a resource such as
>   a dictionary are off-topic. If you have already looked up an answer
>   but still have questions, please include details in your question on
>   the reference you have consulted and what still needs to be clarified.

What do people feel about this close reason? Does it agree with our [help center advice](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? How can we make the close reason as helpful and friendly as possible? Should we somehow link to some example dictionaries?